# How do I cache packages for a snapcraft cleanbuild?

Tags: apt, packaging, snap, lxd

`snapcraft cleanbuild` is supposed to let me build snaps in clean-room environments. Accordingly it starts from a minimal LXD image and installs necessary packages. However, it seems to use the base `archive.ubuntu.com` mirror, which is excruciatingly slow. How do I cache the packages it download?

I could set up `apt-cacher-ng` or another caching proxy, but there's still the problem of getting the snap/LXD combination to use it. It would be best if it had an internal cache like pbuilder does, but if not, then how do I convince it use a different mirror or a proxy for the mirror?

Comment: Could you try Proxy Configuration from this ref https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/16/lxd-2-0-installing-and-configuring-lxd-212/

Comment: @user.dz Unless I'm mistaken that's configuration for the LXD daemon, not for the LXD containers. At any rate, I installed apt-cacher-ng and set it as the proxy according to those instances, but a new run of `snapcraft cleanbuild` isn't using it (apt-cacher-ng has no changes in logs or in the cache dir)

Comment: (The configuration did take effect: a-c-ng doesn't like HTTPS CONNECT requests and I had to unset the HTTPS proxy setting before LXD started working again.)

Comment: Do you think you could accomplish what you want by modifying the hosts file (at least temporarily) to redirect connections destined for archive.ubuntu.com to a server with your cached packages?

Comment: @b_laoshi that would need to be done in the container, not the host server, and if I could do that, I would be able to edit the `sources.list` or `apt.conf` to set a different mirror or a proxy. But snapcraft sets up a container and gets started on building without giving me a chance to do anything, and it seems like a racy way to try and do it manually after snapcraft has started the container.

Comment: [Here's](https://tribaal.io/making-lxd-fly-on-ubuntu-as-well.html) a nice article which details how you can use a package proxy on the host computer, and configure lxd to use that.

Comment: @popey thanks! Would you write an answer summarizing that? I used `environment.http_proxy` instead of `user.user-data/apt`, and a more general squid/apt-cacher-ng proxy instead of squid-deb-proxy, but the core idea is there

Comment: @muru if popey doesn't write an answer would you consider answering your question yourself please? That would shorten the "unanswered list" for those of us browsing through it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic principles as outlined in [popey's suggestion](https://tribaal.io/making-lxd-fly-on-ubuntu-as-well.html) work:

1. Set up a caching proxy on the host (or elsewhere, depending on your preferences, I'll assume host): apt-cacher-ng, squid-deb-proxy or squid itself.
2. Get the host IP address (as seen by the container):

   ```
   export LXD_ADDRESS=$(ip -4 -o address show dev lxdbr0 | awk -F'[ /]*' '{print $4}')
   ```
3. Use it to set the default profile proxy settings:

   ```
   printf '%s\n' '#cloud-config' 'apt:' " proxy: http://$LXD_ADDRESS:8000" |
     lxc profile set default user.user-data -
   ```
4. Success!

However, there are a couple of caveats.

`snapcraft cleanbuild` downloads a lot of packages by some other mechanism than the usual `apt-get`, which isn't affected by this configuration. This insanity is seen in this part of the output:

```
Preparing to pull glue
Pulling glue
Preparing to pull cassandra
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
...
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [3004 B]
Fetched 26.0 MB in 6s (4237 kB/s)
Get:1 ca-certificates-java_20160321_all.deb [12.9 kB]
Fetched 12.9 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
Get:1 libxdmcp6_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb [11.0 kB]
Fetched 11.0 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
Get:1 init-system-helpers_1.29ubuntu4_all.deb [32.3 kB]
Fetched 32.3 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
Get:1 default-jre-headless_1.8-56ubuntu2_amd64.deb [4380 B]
Fetched 4380 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Get:1 default-jdk_1.8-56ubuntu2_amd64.deb [968 B]
Fetched 968 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Get:1 libkrb5-3_1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb [273 kB]
```

There are quite a few of these, and the individual requests make them slow as hell anyway, and that's not counting that that the apt proxy settings set earlier don't affect them.

So, I set the `http_proxy` environment variable instead:

```
lxc profile set default environment.http_proxy "http://$LXD_ADDRESS:3128"
```

And similarly for HTTPS, since some other downloads in the container used HTTPS. I usually prefer apt-cacher-ng, but it doesn't support HTTPS CONNECT, so I switched to squid.